# how to withdraw Paypal USD in the United States when I'm on holiday

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, paypal, cryptocurrency, atm

I've some US dollars in my Irish Paypal account that I want to withdraw when I visit New York on a tourist visa in a month. Is there anyway I can do it direct from Paypal to dollars over there and avoid fees? Or do I have to go USD->EUR->USD

Only US Paypal users can get a Paypal debit card so that's out. I'm thinking maybe Paypal->Western Union and collect in NYC or Paypal->Bitcoin and withdraw over there somehow. Or preload some 3rd party dollar preload card from my Paypal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Contact PayPal and ask them. They will know.  We don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fees and hassle involved with sending the money to a service like Western Union and then converting to cash may outweigh the benefits.

There are, however, some other ways you can use your USD PayPal balance while visiting. Several stores and restaurants in the US now accept PayPal as in-store payment. You can search by location (just use an NYC zip code) at https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/store-locator

So I recommend that you get your US cash the old-fashioned way by exchanging Euros, and buy your souvenirs and meals with PayPal when you can.

Comment: Avoid unnecessary conversion from PayPal USD to EUR to USD. PayPal does not give very good exchange rates.

Answer (score 1):

Where will you be staying? At hotels or with friends? Find out if they will accept PayPal.
It depends on how much money - remember you might want to phone home, will your phone work there? and if so can you top it up using Pay?
I send PayPal payments to a friend in another country as it is so much easier and can work out cheaper than a bank transfer!